# Search bar result automatically refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, uisearchbar, dart-html

Whenever I use Search bar to filter result, it will automatically refresh data (show all listing after showing result) after 2 seconds of showing filter result. How can I stop it from refreshing automatically?

Here is my code printing the result in view:

```
     Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<categories_all>>(
                  future: fetchhome(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<categories_all> data = snapshot.data;
                      datalist = snapshot.data;
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child:category_list_view(
                              shippingToList: data)
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: scU.scale(60),
                        height: scU.scale(60),
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                              kCircularProgressIndicatorColor),
                        ));
                  }),
            ),
```

Search bar performing on changed function when ever text value is changed by the user

```
          child: TextField(

                // onChanged: (text) {
                //   text = text.toLowerCase();
                //   filter(text);
                //
                // },
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: scU.scale(11),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(237, 204, 147, 1),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  filterSearchResults(value);
                },

                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  border: InputBorder.none,


                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Search Rings, Necklaces",

                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(237, 204, 147, 1),
                  ),

                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Satisfy-Regular',
                    fontSize: scU.scale(9.5),


                    color: parseColor("#edcc93"),
                  ),



                ),
              )
```

`filtered method:`
This method is used to filter the search result

```
void filterSearchResults(String query) {
                       List<categories_all> dummySearchList = List<categories_all>();
                       dummySearchList.addAll(datalist);
         if(query.isNotEmpty) {
           List<categories_all> dummyListData = List<categories_all>();
             dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
               if(item.name.contains(query)) {
               dummyListData.add(item);
               }
                });
           setState(() {
             datalist.clear();
             datalist.addAll(dummyListData);
           });
       return;
      }

     }
```

Comment: I dont understand what your trying to do. Are you saying you want a 2 seconds delay on the returned value of your filtered search?

Answer (score 0):

In your `FutureBuilder` you set: `future: fetchhome()`. Assuming this creates a new `Future`, you should make your widget a `StatefulWidget` and call this method *once* inside `initState()` and store the resulting `Future` in a variable in your `State` class.

`build()` should be have no side effects (i.e. it should not modify state). This is because you cannot control when `build()` gets called. For example, if the user opens the keyboard or changes to landscape orientation, it can cause a rebuild.

State objects are longer-lived, and if the widgets haven't changed much (i.e. the `runtimeType` and `key` are the same as the previous frame), the state object will persist, and `initState()` will not be called again. This makes it a good place to start asynchronous work (like a network call).